# Help identifying connections on Kyosan KE750 power supply

Tags: power-supply, pinout

I recently picked up a used 12V power supply for dirt cheap.  It is a Kyosan KE750.  I've searched the Internet for a manual, but have not been able to find any.

Yes, I have plugged it in, and it does output the 12VDC.  Even with a small air compressor for a load, it holds the output voltage steady.

[image]

[image]

1. What is 'LFG' used for?  The other cables were already installed when I got the power supply.  Hot, neutral and ground are connected on 'L', 'N', and 'FG' respectively.
2. What is 'PALS'  trimpot on bottom right used for?   The 'volt adj'  is self explanatory, and works fine.  The 'PALS' adjustment is not obvious to me.
3. As best I can figure out, the cable with plug to the left of AC source, should be for an external AC fan.  Is this correct?  When I got the power supply, it had a 12VDC fan installed on the back.  It was pulling power from OUTPUT.  I don't think that was original.  By the way, that 12VDC fan was dead, so I removed it and will replace.  When I plug the power supply to AC power, and measure with a voltmeter, the black plug reads the same AC voltage as between L-N.
4. Lastly, what is J1 used for?  The cables were cut as shown when I purchased the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be willing to bet that the J1 connector provides access to a pair of remote sense leads. These would be extended to the actual load so that the power supply can account for the voltage loss in the power leads. With up to 63A getting pumped out the voltage at the load could have dropped a fair bit. You can read more about how it works here:  http://power-topics.blogspot.com/2008/07/what-is-remote-sensing.html

Usually these kinds of arrangements have either a switch or a pair of jumper wires attached that tie the sense leads to the local output of the power supply but that doesn't seem to be present on that jumper block.